# Ruby method_missing parameters

Tags: ruby

I have this class:

```
class Mock

    attr_accessor :implementations

    def initialize()
        @implementations = Array.new
    end

    def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
        implementation = findImplementation(method_name, arguments)
        if implementation.nil?
            raise "Undefined method #{method_name}."
        else
            puts "Implemented Method!"
        end
    end

    def implement_method(method_name, parameters, return_value)
        @implementations.unshift(Implementation.new(method_name, parameters, return_value))
        @method_to_mock = nil
        @parameter = nil
        @return_value = nil
    end

    def findImplementation(method_name, args)
        return @implementations.find { |i| i.method_name == method_name && i.parameters == args }
    end

end
```

If I make:

```
m = Mock.new
m.implement_method(:something, 10, true)
m.findImplementation(:something, 10)
```

It returns the implementation I added in the second line. But when I do:

```
m.something(10)
```

It outputs "Undefined Method". Apparently the findImplementation call I make inside the method_missing method is returning nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `find` work? When you `binding.pry` in `implement_method` after unshifting is it in there? Start debugging! :) Unrelated, but it should be `find_implementation`.

Comment: `*argumentss` will create an `Array` which is probably why it is returning `nil` because it cannot find a "Implementation" with parameters `[10]` because you want it to find one with parameters `10`. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish so an answer would be of little use, but this is where the issue is.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes its the problem, how can I solve it to make these values comparables?

Comment: I would need to understand more context to this problem. I am not sure you are going about this correctly but since I am unaware of what your definition of correctly is I am unable to help. Generally I would assume something like `define_singleton_method` is more what you are looking for in `implement_method`

Comment: Keep in mind that in Ruby method names follow the `underscore_name` convention. Using a name like `find_implementation` is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to pass your parameters as an array. (How would you handle multiple params anyway?)

So, your code becomes

```
m = Mock.new
m.implement_method(:something, [10], true)
m.findImplementation(:something, [10])
```